# Laravel 5.3 Pluck vs All

Tags: php, laravel, drop-down-menu, controller, laravel-5.3

I have a question to ask

So I was trying to create a dropdownlist which will show data from another table. In my controller I declare those table in my create function

```
public function create()
{
    $tenants = Tenant::pluck('name','id');
    $categories = Category::pluck('name','id');
    return view('items.create', ['categories' => $categories, 'tenants' => $tenants]);
}
```

and in my views:

```
<div class='form-group'>
                        <label for="category_id" class="col-md-4 control-label">Item Category</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                        <select class="form-control" name="category" id="categories">
                            @foreach($categories as $category)
                            {
                                <option value={{ $category->id }}>{{ $category->name }}</option>
                            }
                            @endforeach
                        </select>   
                        </div>
                    </div>

                     <div class='form-group'>
                        <label for="tenant_id" class="col-md-4 control-label">Tenant</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                        <select class="form-control" name="tenant" id="tenants">
                            @foreach($tenants as $tenant)
                            {
                                <option value={{ $tenant->id }}>{{ $tenant->name }}</option>
                            }
                            @endforeach
                        </select>   
                        </div>

                        </div>
```

And it yields an error: Trying to get property of non-object

but if I change **pluck** to **all** as i did here:

```
public function create()
{
    $tenants = Tenant::all();
    $categories = Category::all();
    return view('items.create', ['categories' => $categories, 'tenants' => $tenants]);
}
```

its working. the problem is I only want to get the value of 'name' & 'id'
and with **all**, it'll also returns the property that i dont need. how can i achieve that with pluck? and if i read the documentation, it says that pluck will retrieve all of the values for a given key but why does my pluck doesn't work? I'm new with php and laravel so any given guide will be so awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `pluck()` you get the data in `[id => 'name']` format, so do this:

```
@foreach($categories as $id => $category)
    <option value={{ $id }}>{{ $category }}</option>
@endforeach
```

And do the same with `$tenants`

Comment: Well its working! thank you for your help, but now i'm confused. if im not mistaken the '=>' is used to assign value to keys in an array. so if i understand your answer correctly, what im getting with `pluck()` is id with the value of name? so instead of 1 as an `Id` I will get a `name`? but when I do this `<option value={{ $id }}>{{ $id }}</option>` it shows that the `id` value is indeed an `id` and not a `name`. so how does that work? I really need to understand

Comment: @ArgaAditya yes, with `pluck()` you're getting an array-like collection with  `[1 => 'SomeCategoryName']` structure where `1` is ID of the category from the table. That's just how `pluck()` works.

Comment: Never mind my previous comment, I've re-read the documentation and I understand now, thank you for your help!